# What is an std::uniform_real_distribution<>::param_type?

Tags: c++, std

When calling an `std::uniform_read_distribution<>`, there is an option to specify the range by passing a `param_type`. `dist(generator, decltype(dist)::param_type{1, 2})` seems to work, but I can't find where `param_type` is defined. Can someone explain what it is or provide a link to its definition in cppreference or the standard?

Comment: It is documented on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution/operator() with link to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomNumberDistribution?

Comment: @user17732522 thanks, the doc was on the last link you provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through the docs more carefully and it turns out I missed it earlier.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomNumberDistribution#:%7E:text=P%2C%20the%20type,%3D%20D%3B)

> `P`, the type named by `D::param_type`, which
>
> - satisfies `CopyConstructible`
> - satisfies `CopyAssignable`
> - satisfies `EqualityComparable`
> - has a constructor taking identical arguments as each of the constructors of `D` that - take arguments corresponding to the distribution parameters.
> - has a member function with the identical name, type, and semantics, as every member function of `D` that returns a parameter of the distribution
> - declares a member typedef `using distribution_type = D;`

[C++17 Standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/rand#:%7E:text=of%20exposition%20only.-,8,using%20distribution_type%20%3D%20%20D%3B,-29.6.2)

> 8. `P` shall satisfy the requirements of `CopyConstructible`, `CopyAssignable`, and `EqualityComparable` types.
> 9. For each of the constructors of `D` taking arguments corresponding to parameters of the distribution, `P` shall have a corresponding constructor subject to the same requirements and taking arguments identical in number, type, and default values. Moreover, for each of the member functions of `D` that return values corresponding to parameters of the distribution, `P` shall have a corresponding member function with the identical name, type, and semantics.
> 10. `P` shall have a declaration of the form `using distribution_type = D`;